# Google Maps - Street view panorama bar

Tags: google-maps

I can't find the library / service / api name to add a street view bar as seen in this picture:

[image]

I just need to have a panorama of images that opens a street view for specific locations.

I've dug through the API docs and I can't find this api.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/)